# How to revert OS X Snow Leopard default theme?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

Yesterday I tried to change my OS X default theme so I installed many themes one of them was Aqua Extreme. Non of them give me what I was looking for as a result I revert pack to default theme using ThemePark program but icons in the main menu lost its shadow. Is it possible to return pack to default theme settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqua Extreme comes with a separate package called Remove Aqua Extreme which restores the default user interface.

If you download the latest Aqua Extreme from http://www.maxthemes.com/downloads/Aqua%20Extreme.dmg
you will find the Remove Aqua Extreme package inside the installation bundle.

Run this package, it should restore everything.